# RDP Child Session

Tags: rdp

Unable to launch client session as described in the following article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/child-sessions

It is explained in the article that credentials are not required to launch child session. However, unable to launch child session using Microsoft RDP activex control. Can't login to client session.

```
axMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting1.Server = "localhost"; Object True = true;
MSTSCLib.IMsRdpExtendedSettings extSettings = (MSTSCLib.IMsRdpExtendedSettings)axMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting1.GetOcx();
extSettings.set_Property("ConnectToChildSession", True); 

IMsRdpClient7 msRdpClient = axMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting1.GetOcx() as IMsRdpClient7;
msRdpClient.AdvancedSettings7.EnableCredSspSupport = true; 

axMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting1.Connect();
```

Can somebody please provide a working sample or through some light ?

Thanks, Sri